# need to know how many connections i have on a specific port. using netstat

Tags: netstat, cmd.exe

need to know how many connections i have on a specific port.

For example that i have 10 connection on port 80.

Is it possible to do on **netsta**t or in any program ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port

You can use the command:

netstat -np  | find "port #"

Also, if you want only the number of connections, you can use this command:

netstat -np  | find /C "port #"